# CD into directory with "-" in the beginning

Tags: bash, sh

I have a problem with cd-ing into folder named "--Recovery Files" and can't remember how to escape dashes in the filename. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
cd -- '--Recovery Files'
```

The `--` tells `cd` that no further command line arguments should be treated as options.

Answer (score 10):

2 choices:

1. `cd -- --Recovery\ Files`
2. `cd ./--Recovery\ Files`

Answer (score 5):

```
cd -- '--Recovery Files'
```

The `--` by itself indicates that subsequent words beginning with a dash are not to be interpreted as command-line options.